# how to count values via stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying to take in a stream of objects which have a variable `vote` (0 to 100). I am trying to count the occurrences of each to the tens place. eg:

```
23,44,48 returns 0:1,  1:2,  0:3,  2:4,...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NewClass {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            class Temp{
                Long vote=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100);
            }

            ArrayList<Temp> t=new ArrayList(); 
            t.add(new Temp());
            t.add(new Temp());
            t.add(new Temp());

            Map<Integer, Long> counters = t.stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> { 
                    return ((int)p.vote/10);
                }, Collectors.counting()));

            Collection<Long> values = counters.values();
            Integer[] res = values.toArray(new Long[values.size()]);
        }
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: The res variable should be of type Long[] I believe.

Comment: @Aominè Yes, or maybe the initialization of the `ArrayList` (it's lacking the `<>`), can't remember if it issues a warning or an error.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner didn’t notice that. Good shout!.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be two errors in your code and one warning for using a raw `ArrayList`.

The first issue is in this line:

```
return ((int)p.vote/10);
```

`p.vote` is of type `Long` and you cannot cast it to a type `int`. This can be solved with:

```
p -> p.vote.intValue() / 10
```

The second issue is that the `res` variable should be of type `Long[]` not `Integer[]`.

Finally, the warning can be erased by changing this:

```
ArrayList<Temp> t = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<Temp> t = new ArrayList<>();
```

Complete code:

```
ArrayList<Temp> t = new ArrayList<>();
t.add(new Temp());
t.add(new Temp());
t.add(new Temp());

Map<Integer, Long> counters = 
               t.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.vote.intValue()/10, 
                         Collectors.counting()));

Collection<Long> values = counters.values();
Long[] res = values.toArray(new Long[values.size()]);
```